# How can we make sure that the input values are normally distributed?

Tags: javascript, math, statistics

[image]

I am using a bar-rating plug in to make the user self-rate one's skill ability. 
As I change the box rating it will automatically calculate the sum of levels (right now it's 20). I wanted to restrict the user from choosing full-level for all skills by making it normally distributed.

Considering the user can add more skills, how can I make it normally distributed mathematically? (what does the average has to be?)

Comment: Please add a [mcve] using the `<>` snippet editor - if this is not a code issue, please go to math.stackexchange.com

Comment: When theres +1 at one slider, do -1/(n-1) at every other slider where n is the number of all sliders.

Comment: @Jonasw how do we know if the data is normally distributed? Is it when mean == median ?

Comment: Are you sure you want to check for normal distribution? I don't see the point of this. Five samples are just not enough to verify any distribution. Also, all categories having maximum value can be seen as a normal distribution (with very small variance).